# What is the probability of being picked as a group of two out of a group of six people.

Tags: probability

So I have this question on basic probability that confuses/anoys me a little bit. 
Lets say we have a group of six people and you need to pick 2 of them for a party committee. Those two people can be picked in 15 different ways.

Lets say one of the persons is named John. Then what is the probability of John being picked as one of the two in a draw?

The two people can be put together in 15 different ways, and John is in 5 of the "groups", så the probability would "just" be 1/3. But what annoys me a little bit, is if John is picked in a draw:
Change of John being picked first = 1/6. Change of John being picked second = 1/5. And then by just using the addition principle the change of John being picked is 11/15.

Can anyone explain to me where my mind takes the wrong turn :-)

Answer (score 1):

Chance of John being picked second is actually not $\frac{1}{5}$. Note that if John is picked first, he cannot be picked second anymore, so when you say $P(\text{"John picked second"})$, you actually mean $P(\text{"John not picked first and John picked second"})$. This is equivalent to  $\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{6}$.

Then using addition principle as you mentioned, we get the same answer $\frac{1}{3}$